# Как модернизировать код, чтобы он не считал долго?

Tags: python

```
def F(n):
    if n<3:
        return 1
    elif n>2 and n%2!=0:
        return F(n-1)-F(n-2)
    elif n>2 and n%2==0:
        k=0
        for i in range(1,n):
            k+=F(i)
        return(k)

print(F(20))
```

Comment: что он хоть делает этот код?

Comment: а что он считает-то? Как минимум условия можно и нужно упростить. Если n НЕ меньше 3, то очевидно, что n больше двух, поэтому проверка n>2 - лишняя. И если n%2 НЕ не равно 0, то очевидно, то n%2 равно 0, т.к. там всего два варианта. Так что и проверка n%2==0 тоже лишняя

Comment: Долго - это сколько?

Comment: Очевидно - упростить формулу, например ```for i in range(1,n):  k+=F(i)``` - совершенно ужасная идея, сохраняйте значения чтоб каждый рекурсивный вызов не пересчитывать всё заного

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ленивый" вариант - добавить к функции кеширующий декоратор:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def F(n):
    ...
```

В этом случае `F(1000)` вычисляет за 100мс.

Comment: Это работает с любыми функциями?

Comment: @Malvina Ну, в теории да, а на практике кэш - это не "серебряная пуля", надо смотреть сценарий использования, где-то он отлично работает, а где-то не очень )

Answer (score 4):

Время приведённой функции экспоненциальное, как у рекурсивного вычисления Фибоначчи в лоб.

А вот алгоритм гораздо быстрее, квадратичный. Но его можно сделать линейным, если модифицировать расчёт суммы.

```
def FF(n):
    a = [1]*(n+1)
    for i in range(3, n+1):
        if i%2:
            a[i] = a[i-1]-a[i-2]
        else:
            a[i] = sum(a[1:i])
    return a[n]
```

Для того, чтобы не пересчитывать всю сумму, можно завести список частичных сумм и обновлять его при каждом расчете. Однако нетрудно заметить, что последняя четная ячейка уже содержит сумму элементов левее нее, так что можно обойтись без дополнительного хранилища.

Линейный алгоритм:

```
def FF(n):
    a = [1]*(n+1)
    for i in range(3, n+1):
        if i%2:
            a[i] = a[i-1]-a[i-2]
        else:
            a[i] = a[i-1] + 2 * a[i-2]
    return a[n]
```

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. в коде почти все значения вычисляются по многу раз, например, F(18) будет вычисляться 4 раза (если я не ошибся), и чем ниже аргумент функции F(), тем больше раз он будет вычисляться снова и снова, причем количество этих раз растет в геометрической прогрессии. Т.е. каждый их этих 4 раз влечет за собой десятки и сотни вычислений F() для чисел меньше 18. Поэтому нужно использовать [мемоизацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), т.е. сохранять значения F() для каждого числа в список или словарь и брать потом сразу готовое, чтобы не вычислять по сотне раз одно и то же.

Comment: О!, у этого даже термин есть :) просвятили :)